# Does anybody know what sort of fossil this could be?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, microbiology

[image: .]enter image description here[image]

Found in rural North Dakota. Small rock with black circular indentations.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you please provide more pictures, with better lighting of the "fossils". It may not be a fossil at all, but rather some sort of inclusion in the rock.  Fossil ID is on-topic for [Earth Science SE](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/), but you would need to request migration - don't cross-post!

Comment: it looks like marks made by animals living on the stone probably made under water,it is very unlikely to be fossils the rock is rounded most likely when submerged under water.

Comment: Thanks guys! Any bit of info helps.